# Sorting numerically but not alphabetically when numbers are equal

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have a file like this:

```
A 0.77
C 0.98
B 0.77
Z 0.77
G 0.65
```

I want to sort the file numerically in descending order. I used this code:

```
sort -gr -k2,2 file.txt
```

I obtain this:

```
C 0.98 
Z 0.77
B 0.77
A 0.77
G 0.65
```

In my real file I have several columns with the same number and they are ordered alphabetically. What I want is to sort numerically but not alphabetically when the numbers are equal, I want to obtain those columns unsorted alphabetically:

```
C 0.98
B 0.77  
Z 0.77
A 0.77
G 0.65
```

But any random order is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `sort`:

```
sort -k2rn -k1R file
```

```
C 0.98
B 0.77
Z 0.77
A 0.77
G 0.65
```

There are 2 sort options used:

- `-k2rn`: First sort key is column 2; numerical, reverse
- `-k1R`: Second sort key is column 1; **random**

Comment: I obtained the same result, the file is ordered alphabetically in reverse order.

Comment: Done. What I want is apply `sort -R` maintaining the numerical sort.

Answer (score 1):

One in GNU awk that preserves the order of the first field (random in, equally random out):

```
$ awk ' {
    a[$2]=a[$2] (a[$2]==""?"":FS) $1       # append $1 values to hash, indexed on $1
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"  # set for traverse order for index order...
    for(i in a) {                          # ... and use it here
        n=split(a[i],b)
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)                  # preserve the input order
            print b[j],i                   # output
    }
}' file
C 0.98
A 0.77
B 0.77
Z 0.77
G 0.65
```

Testing reverse order:

```
$ tac file | awk '# above awk script'
C 0.98
Z 0.77
B 0.77
A 0.77
G 0.65
```